# azure - linux virtual machine stuck at "stopping"

Tags: azure, restart, azure-virtual-machine, hung

i have been experimenting with azure services using my msdn account. i created a suse enterprise linux virtual machine. deployed sonar+mysql and a few simple java applications. everything was fine for almost a month, until last weekend. i tried to connect via ssh and could not get a response. i tried accessing the sonar website, again no response. i used the axure portal to restart the vm, it seemed to restart but still no response. i used the azure portal to stop the service. its status has been at "stopping" for several days. any thoughts about what i can do to regain connectivity?

Answer (score 0):

It is very much possible that something in your virtual machine had caused this issue and your best bet is to report this problem to following dedicated forum realted with Windows Azure Linux Virtual Machine so you will get proper assistance to troubleshoot your problem:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforLinux/threads